# Зачем используется qmap_test?

Tags: оптимизация, qt, c++

Не пойму, что делает **qmap_test()**, где кроме MSDN можно почитать, можно даже на англ. Понимаю, что это для ускорения вычислений и распараллеливания энных, но все-таки код из проекта игры.

Более все-го интересует что делает  **static U32 hash(IVEC qstr)**

```
typedef __int16 I16;
typedef unsigned __int16 U16;
typedef __int32 I32;
typedef unsigned __int32 U32;
typedef __m128i IVEC;

static IVEC qstr_load(const char* pStr) {
    union {
        IVEC v;
        char c[16];
    } qs;
    qs.v = _mm_setzero_si128();
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        char c = pStr[i];
        if (!c) break;
        qs.c[i] = c;
    }
    return qs.v;
}

static bool qstr_eq(IVEC qs0, IVEC qs1) {
    return _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_cmpeq_epi8(qs0, qs1)) == 0xFFFF;
}

template <typename T, int TBL_SIZE=0x100, int MAX_NODE=0x400> class QMap {
protected:
    IVEC mKey[MAX_NODE];
    T mVal[MAX_NODE];
    I16 mLnk[MAX_NODE];
    I16 mTbl[TBL_SIZE];
    I32 mIdx;

    static U32 hash(IVEC qstr) {
        IVEC zero = _mm_setzero_si128();
        IVEC t0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(qstr, zero);
        IVEC t1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(qstr, zero);
        t1 = _mm_add_epi16(t0, t1);
        t0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(t1, zero);
        t1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(t1, zero);
        t1 = _mm_add_epi16(t0, t1);
        t0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(t1, zero);
        t1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(t1, zero);
        t1 = _mm_add_epi32(t0, t1);
        t0 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(t1, zero);
        t1 = _mm_add_epi32(t0, t1);
        U32 h = _mm_extract_epi16(t1, 0);
        return h % TBL_SIZE;
    }

public:
    QMap() : mIdx(0) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < TBL_SIZE; ++i) {
            mTbl[i] = -1;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_NODE; ++i) {
            mLnk[i] = -1;
        }
    }

    void put(const char* pKey, T val) {
        IVEC key = qstr_load(pKey);
        int h = hash(key);
        int idx = mIdx;
        if (idx >= MAX_NODE) {
            return;
        }
        if (mTbl[h] < 0) {
            mTbl[h] = idx;
        } else {
            h = mTbl[h];
            while (true) {
                if (mLnk[h] < 0) {
                    mLnk[h] = idx;
                    break;
                }
                h = mLnk[h];
            }
        }
        mKey[idx] = key;
        mVal[idx] = val;
        ++mIdx;
    }

    bool get(IVEC key, T* pVal) {
        int h = hash(key);
        int idx = mTbl[h];
        while (idx >= 0) {
            if (qstr_eq(key, mKey[idx])) {
                if (pVal) {
                    *pVal = mVal[idx];
                }
                return true;
            }
            idx = mLnk[idx];
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool get(const char* pKey, T* pVal) {
        IVEC key = qstr_load(pKey);
        return get(key, pVal);
    }
};

static int idx2val(int idx) {return idx*idx;}

static void qmap_test() {
    int i;
    int n = 100;
    char key[256];
    int val;
    QMap<int> map;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        val = idx2val(i);
        ::sprintf_s(key, "%d", val);
        map.put(key, val);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        val = idx2val(i);
        ::sprintf_s(key, "%d", val);
        int mval = 0;
        if (map.get(key, &mval)) {
            if (mval != val) {
                ::printf("mismatch: %d != %d\n", mval, val);
            } else {
                ::printf("key = %s, val = %d\n", key, mval);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

добавим комментариев

```
static void qmap_test() {
    int i;
    int n = 100;
    char key[256]; // это просто буфер преобразования числа в строку
    int val;
    QMap<int> map; // это хэшмап
    // в цикле добавляем в мап n пар "n"->n*n
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        val = idx2val(i);
        ::sprintf_s(key, "%d", val);
        map.put(key, val);
    }

    // а теперь  в цикле проверяем, есть ли эти значения в мапе.
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        val = idx2val(i);
        ::sprintf_s(key, "%d", val);
        int mval = 0;
        if (map.get(key, &mval)) {
            // если значения не совпадает - выводим в лог.
            if (mval != val) {
                ::printf("mismatch: %d != %d\n", mval, val);
            } else {
                ::printf("key = %s, val = %d\n", key, mval);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

то есть, это просто тестирования работы класса [QMap](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QMap.html) из поставки Qt. Зачем - не понятно, возможно просто не доверяет человек.

С второй функцией немного сложнее. Для начала нужно посмотреть на все эти функции - [Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/).

```
static U32 hash(IVEC qstr) {
        IVEC zero = _mm_setzero_si128(); // заполним 128 бит нулями
        IVEC t0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(qstr, zero); // извлечение младших
        IVEC t1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(qstr, zero); // и старших байт
        t1 = _mm_add_epi16(t0, t1);  // и складываем
        t0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(t1, zero); // и ещё раз повторяем
        t1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(t1, zero); // но теперь работаем с 16 битными
        t1 = _mm_add_epi16(t0, t1);
        t0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(t1, zero); // тоже с 32битными
        t1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(t1, zero);
        t1 = _mm_add_epi32(t0, t1);
        t0 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(t1, zero); // чуть по другому
        t1 = _mm_add_epi32(t0, t1);       // но теперь с 64 битами
        U32 h = _mm_extract_epi16(t1, 0);  // и просто возвращаем последние 16 бит
        return h % TBL_SIZE;
    }
```

рассмотрим детальнее первое преобразование, остальные по логике делаются

итак, пусть на входе у нас 012356789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF - 128 бит.

```
IVEC t0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(qstr, zero); // извлечение младших
```

теперь в t0 будет 001020305060708090A0B0C0D0E0F

```
IVEC t1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(qstr, zero); // и старших байт
```

теперь в t1 будет те же 001020305060708090A0B0C0D0E0F, но это потому, что просто я выбрал одинаковые две половинки.

```
t1 = _mm_add_epi16(t0, t1);  // и складываем группами по 16 бит
```

t1 = 000206080A0C0E000206080A0C0E

Дальше все подобно, только меняется разрядность.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли разобраться, если используется SSE - то это дает возможность распараралелить вычисления и ускорить выполнение запись-чтение?

Comment: sse дает возможность делать однотипные операции над массивом чисел (не совсем массивом, а таким маленьким на 64/128/256 бит). Если данные хорошо подготовить, то да, можно до 4-8 раз получить прирост в скорости (если очень хорошо подготовить данные на специфических алгоритмах). Я некоторых своих задачах получал трикратный прирост (yuv-rgb кодирование).

А вот ускорить чтение-запись sse как бы может (там даже есть команда копирования блока памяти). Но для этого не предназначена.